# Clarification on definition: $\Gamma$-varying function (Extreme value theory)

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, extreme-value

In Extreme Values, Regular Variation and Point Processes, there is the following definition:

A non-decreasing $U$ is $\Gamma$-varying if $U$ is defined on an interval $(x_l, x_0)$, $\lim_{x \to x_0^-} U(x) = \infty$, and there exists positive function $f$ defined on $(x_l, x_0)$ such that for all $x$,

$\lim_{t \to x_0} \frac{U(t+xf(t))}{U(t)} = e^x$.

[image]

What would be an example of a Gamma-varying function? I'm having trouble coming up with an example, and to me, it's not clear for what $f$ we have $t+xf(t)<x_0$ eventually as $t \to x_0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, especially for finite $x_0$.